# Formula to count a value only once in a given row

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, countif

Been trying to nut this one out for a while and hope I can explain it clearly.....

It is a formula from an employee roster that simply adds the number of hours each person works in a given day. However, in the case where an employees name appears more than once in a row (the row representing the day of week) the formula I have is multiplying hours by the number of times that name appears.

Here is my current formula:
`=COUNTIF($G4:$W4,AI$3)*($AF4+$AG4)`

It takes the employee name in cell AI3 and in this case looks along row 4 from columns G-W. If the name in AI3 appears in the range G4:W4 then it adds the hours in cells AF4 and AG4. Sometimes an employees name may appear twice in the range G4:W4 because they are performing more than one task on the day. In this instance their hours are multiplied. I am looking for a COUNTIF formula that will count the name only once.

Help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting your countif() in an if() statement, like so:

```
=if(countif(xxx)>=1,1,0)
```

So the result is 1 as long as they appear once or more, if they are not there then the result is 0.

You may need to do:

```
=iferror(if(countif(xxx)>=1,1,0),0)
```

as I am on my phone and cannot test...

Or you could use find() and as long as that comes back true, well with a position, then they are there - unique names may be needed...

Comment: Thanks heaps! Your first example (wrapping the countif() in an if() statement) works a treat.